# SQL Server Management Studio Agent Jobs List View

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server

I've recently moved from using SQL 2000 Enterprise Manager to SQL 2008 R2 Management Studio.

I am administering the SQL Agent Jobs of a remote SQL 2000 Server and need to find the Next Run details of several of the Jobs.

In Enterprise Manager when selecting the Jobs node of the tree view, all the jobs are listed in a grid which includes the Next Run Date.

In Management Studio the jobs are listed in the tree view and I can find no way of accessing the Next Run info.

I have tried the Object Explorer Details view but this only includes Name, Status and Policy Health State columns.

Is there any way to view this info in SQL Management Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the **Job Activity Monitor** under SQL Server Agent?

Comment: I get an error: `Cannot show requested dialog. - Additional information: - Unable to execute requested command. - jobs (SqlManagerUI)`

Comment: OK, it's because I am using the SQL Express Advanced version of SSMS. This doesn't support Job Activity Monitor (http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/354939/cannot-open-dialog-in-job-activity-monitor)